# MSSQL DateTime-поле UTC

Tags: sql, sql-server, время

Добрый день!

Подскажите, возможно кто-то сталкивался... Есть ли T-SQL (MSSQL) функция для преобразования уже записанных значений `DateTime` в таблице в универсальное время (где нет поправки на перевод часов).

`CONVERT(CHAR(), DateTimeField, 127)` и `CONVERT(CHAR(), DateTimeField, 126)` почему-то дают однотипное значение, хотя везде написано, что первое должно выводить Z - часовой сдвиг.

Конструкция `DATEDIFF(s, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE())` не подходит, так как даёт сдвиг только на текущий момент, который может отличаться от полгода назад...

Возможно есть какие-то решение на основе локалей? Или можно задать временную зону для транзакции/соединения?

СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поле datetime не хранит в себе UTC смещение, поэтому сдвиг "на полгода назад" из него получить не удастся.
Если необходимо хранить данные с разным смещением, используйте datetimeoffset.
И почитайте первоисточник:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186724.aspx

Comment: Да. Я в принципе и сам до этого дошел, но очень хотелось, чтоб кто-то подтвердил, что не сильно ошибаюсь.

Увы, база уже готовая, и что хуже - с внушительными данными - новое исправить не сложно; старое пришлось долго и нужно ровнять руками по точкам перевода часов))) 

Спасибо!